# working with audio using ruby/sdl

Tags: ruby, audio, sdl, wav, playback

I need some help working with sdl. At this point all I'm trying to do is get ruby to play an audio file using the rubysdl gem (I really can't find much out there on this gem except for the documentation). this is my code as of right now:

```
  #!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'sdl'

SDL.init(SDL::INIT_AUDIO)
sound = SDL::Mixer.open(44100, SDL::Mixer::DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 1024)
sound.load("rebel-theme.wav")
```

but when I try to run it I get:

```
  sdlaudio.rb:7:in `<main>': private method `load' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I'm still pretty new to ruby and I may be in over my head here but I've found that at least for me thats the best way to learn (once I actually start to catch on which as far as sdl is concerned, I have not, lol).
My goal with this app is to make a simple audio player, but down the road my larger goal is to work with audio synthesis. I'm assuming the sdl gem is where I want to be for those goals but I may be wrong there too. So I guess my next question is, am I on the right track diving into 'rubysdl' or is there another avenue I should be exploring?